# Disabling select input depending on previous select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What I'm trying to achieve here is this: I have a select input that has 3 options : Sale, Rent, Wanted. Depending on which option is selected, there are 3 other select inputs. So lets say I choose Sale then it should show the `property sale` select input and hide the other two, if I choose Rent then it should show the `property rent` select input and the hide the other two.

The hiding works well but my issue is when i submit for search using GET, it passes the data of the two other hidden select inputs because they are not disabled. I tried disabling them depending on selection as shown in the below code but it didn't work. Any help?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
   $('#type').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val() === "sale"){
    $("#propertyrent").hide();
    $("#propertywanted").hide();
    $("#pricetype").show();
    $("#propertysale").show();
    document.getElementById("propertyrent").disabled=true;
    document.getElementById("propertywanted").disabled=true;
    } 
    else if( $(this).val() === "rent"){
    $("#pricetype").hide();
    $("#propertyrent").show();
    $("#propertywanted").hide();
    $("#propertysale").hide();
    document.getElementById('propertysale').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('propertywanted').disabled=true;

    } 
    else if( $(this).val() === "wanted"){
    $("#pricetype").hide();
    $("#propertyrent").hide();
    $("#propertywanted").show();
    $("#propertysale").hide();
    document.getElementById('propertyrent').disabled=true;
    document.getElementById('propertysale').disabled=true;
    } 
});


</script>

            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Type</label>
                <select name="type" id="type">
                    <option value="sale">Sale</option>
                    <option value="rent">Rent</option>
                    <option value="wanted">Wanted</option>
                </select>       


<div id="propertysale">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Property</label>
                <select name="propertysale" id="propertysale" class="form-control col-sm-12">
                <option value="all">Any</option>
                <option value="houses">Houses</option>

                <option value="apartments">Apartments</option>

                <option value="land">Land</option>


                <option value="buildings">Buildings</option>

                <option value="wfsc" >Warehouse / Factory / Store / Chalet</option>
                </select>
        </div>

        <div id="propertyrent" style="display:none;">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Property</label>
                <select name="propertyrent" id="propertyrent" class="form-control col-sm-12">
                <option value="all">Any</option>
                <option value="houses">Houses</option>
                <option value="apartments">Apartments / Flats</option>
                <option value="wfsc" >Warehouse / Factory / Store / Chalet</option>
                </select>
        </div>

        <div id="propertywanted" style="display:none;">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Property</label>

                <select name="propertywanted" id="propertywanted" class="form-control col-sm-12">
                <option value="all">Any</option>
                <option value="houses">Houses</option>

                <option value="apartments">Apartments</option>

                <option value="land">Land</option>


                <option value="buildings">Buildings</option>

                <option value="wfsc" >Warehouse / Factory / Store / Chalet</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Have you tried display=none? document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";

Comment: @TobiObeck Its not about hiding them only, when they are hidden without being disabled they still submit data to the form. I want to prevent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery selector for any input inside div to disabling them:

```
$("#yourDiv input, #yourDiv select").prop("disabled", true);
```

To remove disabled: prop("disabled", false);

Comment: #yourDiv input you mean the div with the style="display:none" ..? right? and the #yourDiv select with the select name/id?

Comment: For example:
else if( $(this).val() === "wanted"){
    $("#pricetype").hide();
    $("#propertyrent").hide();
    $("#propertywanted").show();
    $("#propertysale").hide();
   $("#propertyrent input, #propertyrent select").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#propertysale input, #propertysale select").prop("disabled", true);
    }

Comment: Thank you! Wish i could say love you! :D

Comment: i have a question if possible: if i select an options thats not available in other select boxes and then i change the first selection, it disables everything?

Answer (score 0):

here div and your **selectbox id is same 'propertyrent','propertywanted','propertysale'** change this.
and when you hide or disable selectbox set value **blank** of select box

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are not disabling the select menu. You are disabling the div that contains the select menu

```
<div id="propertyrent" style="display:none;">..

<select name="propertyrent" id="propertyrent" c...
```

Use different id for both. It will work